# Gallio not working with sonar-runner

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, gallio, sonar-runner, opencover

I'm trying to get sonar-runner to run Gallio and OpenCover on my .net application.

I've set up the following:

> Sonarqube v4.3.2
>
> Gallio v3.4.14
>
> NUnit v2.6.3
>
> OpenCover v4.5
>
> Sonar-runner v2.4

Here is what I have in my sonar-project.properties file (the things conserning Gallio)

```
\#Gallio

sonar.gallio.mode=

sonar.gallio.coverage.tool=OpenCover 

sonar.donet.visualstudio.testProjectPattern=*Test* 

sonar.opencover.installDirectory=C:\\Program Files (x86)\\OpenCover\\

sonar.dotnet.test.assemblies=**\\bin\\Debug\\*.Tests.dll

sonar.gallio.runner=Local
```

I have tried all sorts of variations of this config file but the weird thing is that when I run sonar-runner, even with parameters -X or -e, there is absolutely no mention of Gallio or OpenCover in the output. It's like the sonar runner is just skipping the Gallio section completely!

Does anyone here have a clue of what might be going on ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest versions of the C# Plugin do not support the automatic execution of Gallio (see [this documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Upgrade+from+the+.NET+ecosystem+version+2.1)).

Starting with C# 3.0, only the reuse of reports is supported to get test and coverage information for .NET projects. Please read the [documentation page of the C# plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/C%23+Plugin) to know how to do that.

Comment: Thank you Fabrice, that sorts it out then :)